# How can I make a large image respond nicely on all screen sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's img-responsive class.

I have an image (1920x1200) that looks too big, in terms of height, on a lg screen and correct on an xs screen.

If I cut the height of the image, it looks correct on a lg screen, but way too small on an xs screen.

I tried setting the image's max-height, but it also changes the width, resulting in gray space on either side of the image.

How can I make a large image respond nicely on all screen sizes?

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row hero-image-container vertical-align">
    <img src="../../static/images/house.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h1 class="hero-image-address">
      <i class="hero-location-icon ion-ios-location" ariahidden="true"></i> Address Here
    </h1>
    <div class="hero-image-after"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that using media queries to alter the dimensions of the container or image will alter the displayed sized, but the full image will still be loaded - then the browser has to redimension the image - which is not very performant. Also a REALLY large image may be prohibitive in download speed / page weight for small devices and users data plans.
You may find srcset to be of use. This is an attribute that allows the browser to select from a series of options and will only load the best fit. It is always better to deliver the correctly sized image - rather than relying on browser resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Yasin's answer looks quite practical.

Add media queries to make the image container's height look good in various common viewport size, like so:

```css
.imageContainer{
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* common tablet portrait */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .imageContainer{ max-height: 800px; }
}

/* common tablet landscape */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .imageContainer{ max-height: 900px; }
}

/* common 15" notebook */
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .imageContainer{ max-height: 1000px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a52/wallpapers-pixel-landscapes-wallpaper-mountain-mountains-large-landscape.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set maxHeight on the parent container and set overflow to hidden. So it will cut off the image. Something like this. This image is 1080px but I am only showing 600px of it.

```css
.imageContainer{
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a52/wallpapers-pixel-landscapes-wallpaper-mountain-mountains-large-landscape.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-holder {
   min-height: 500px;
   background: url('http://wfiles.brothersoft.com/w/waterfall-hd-wallpaper_171535-1920x1200.jpg') center center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
   .img-holder {
    min-height: 300px;
   }
  }

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
   .img-holder {
    min-height: 200px;
   }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row hero-image-container vertical-align">

   <div class="img-holder">

   </div>
   <h1 class="hero-image-address">
     <i class="hero-location-icon ion-ios-location" ariahidden="true"></i> Address Here
   </h1>
   <div class="hero-image-after"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Try using it as background-image like this with background-size:cover.